# How eval defrecord generated by defmacro

Tags: clojure

that's a really weird case!

I've reached to a defrecord definition when I call my macro but I only get the code without the evaluation.

```
(defmacro protocol-impl [protocol-definition]
  ``(defrecord ~(symbol "my-wrapper") [~(symbol "e#")]
     ~@(let [[type# protocol-functions#] ~protocol-definition]
         (conj
          (map
           (fn [[function-name# function-args#]]
             `(~function-name# ~function-args#
                               (~function-name# ~(symbol "e#") ~@(next function-args#))))
           protocol-functions#) type#))

))



(protocol-impl (adapt-super-impls (first (get-methods (Example.)))))
;;=> (clojure.core/defrecord
;;  my-wrapper
;;  [e#]
;;  wrapper.core.Welcome
;;  (say_bye [this# a# b#] (say_bye e# a# b#))
;;  (greetings [this#] (greetings e#)))
```

if I try

```
(my-wrapper. (Example.))
=> Unable to resolve classname: my-wrapper
```

but if I eval the output generated by my macro call in nrepl the defrecord is evaluated fine

Any ideas to get this macro working, or how could I work with my current macro output?

[here the gist with 70 lines of code](https://gist.github.com/tangrammer/3a1b9cdc79d2b3a766ea)

Thanks in advance
Juan

PS: I know that this double `` caused this behaviour but to define a defrecord you need all protocols and fns following in the same list definion, and I didn't find a better way to achieve it

Comment: I'm not following why you need the double ``... what happens when you just do one `?

Comment: @DaveYarwood the problem here is to get into (defrecord ... ) all the arguments on the same list, without nested lists. I don't find a better way to achieve it :)

Answer (score 0):

OK, I took a look through some of the code in your gist at least enough to understand what it's all doing. Admittedly the inner workings of your `protocol-impl` macro are confusing to me, especially all of the extra back-ticks, and it seems to me like your code could be refactored to be less confusing by using a general structure like this:

```
(defmacro foo [bar]
  (let [baz  (symbol (some calculation here))
        quux (map some-fn (take 2 some-collection))] 
    `(do stuff with ~baz and ~quux)))
```

(The actual values in the `let` binding are just arbitrary pseudocode; the idea here is just to avoid having a big mess of quoting and unquoting within your macro definition, by pulling some of that calculation out into a `let` binding, or even into a separate function outside of the macro definition)

But putting that issue aside, this will solve your problem of the `defrecord` form being returned instead of eval'd:

```
(defmacro protocol-impl [protocol-definition]
  `(eval 
    `(defrecord ... etc.

(protocol-impl '[wrapper.core.Welcome 
                 ([say_bye [this a b]] 
                  [greetings [this]])])

(my-wrapper. (Example.))
;=> #wrapper.core.my-wrapper{:e# #wrapper.core.Example{}}
```

So why does that work and not this?

```
(defmacro protocol-impl [protocol-definition]
  `(defrecord ... etc.

(protocol-impl '[wrapper.core.Welcome 
                 ([say_bye [this a b]] 
                  [greetings [this]])])

;=> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
;=> Attempting to call unbound fn: #'clojure.core/unquote ...
```

I have absolutely no idea. Supposedly it has something to do with using an unquote (`~`) outside of a syntax-quoted form, but I don't understand how that's possible if the whole macro definition is wrapped in a syntax-quote...

Comment: Thanks for taking your time on that, when you get ;=> Attempting to call unbound fn: #'clojure.core/unquote is caused by trying to "~" inside a current unquote list like that ~() or ~@(). So if you have double syntax quoting `` you'll need double unquote ~~ to split the param value.

Comment: But in the example above, if you remove the second back-tick (halfway down the macro definition, in the anonymous function), so that there is only one backtick at the beginning of the macro definition, you still get the same error for some reason.